# How to zip files older than 30 days in java

Tags: java

I have a directory with multiple folders and there is a lot of files older than 30 days which I would like to compress, is there a way I can zip the files only older than 30 days?

I have a code that zips all the files but I want it to only zip the files older than 30 days.

Comment: What have you tried? Couldn't you get each `File`'s `lastModified` and compare it to the current date?

Comment: I havent tried anything yet, because I am not sure how to do it..

Comment: I have to basically make a app that zips all the files older than 30 days, so what im going to do is choose the folder path then all the files that are older than 30 days should be zipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let your zipping loop go through your directories and let it check the files age by using `.lastModified()`.

You can then create a difference between the current time an the last modification of the given file. And if it is greater than your 30 day, you let your code zip it.

Note: `.lastModified()` gives you the time in ms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 7 Files API to get the attributes of the files to select the desired ones. In the following example I get the creation time:

```
Path path = ... // path to the file
BasicFileAttributes attributes = 
    Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
FileTime creationTime = attributes.creationTime();
```

See: [Interface BasicFileAttributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html)